# What is the name of the widget which slides in at the bottom of the page and recommends more articles for reading?

Tags: javascript, looking-for-a-script, widgets

I see this on more and more pages. I can't show an example right know, but the widget is a small box sliding in at the right bottom of the page and it usually says "Did you read this?" or something like that and shows an article title.

Is there a name for this widget? Is it a jquery plugin or part of some other javascript library? I'm looking for its name, so I can get more info about it.

Comment: Can you provide a URL where this script is in use? / Have you looked at the source code for details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably referring to the New York Times slidebox. They were one of the first, or at least highest-profile sites to use the technique. There's a [demo here](http://xaviershay.github.com/nytimes-slider/) of a plugin someone wrote, with link to Github for source. And here's a [tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/04/13/end-of-page-slide-out-box/) implementing a simple version with just some custom jQuery-based JS.